# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2j}\mathrm dx}{(x^4+2ax^2+1)^{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am working on an integral and I need some help. From the book Irresistible Integrals, I am given the problem of obtaining a closed form for:

> $$N(j,n;a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2j}\mathrm dx}{(x^4+2ax^2+1)^{n+1}},\quad n,j\in\Bbb N,\, 0\leq j\leq 2n+1,\,a>-1$$

I have been able to make significant progress, but there is an integral that I am stuck on. Here's what I've done. Using the substitution $x=1/u$, it is easily shown that 
$$N(j,n;a)=N(2n-j+1,n;a)\tag{1}$$
With $x=\tan\frac{t}2$, we have that 
$$N(j,n;a)=\frac12\int_0^\pi \frac{\tan(t/2)^{2j}\sec(t/2)^2\mathrm dt}{\left[\tan(t/2)^4+2a\tan(t/2)^2+1\right]^{n+1}}$$
Which boils down to 
$$N(j,n;a)=\frac1{2(2-2a)^{n+1}}\int_0^\pi\frac{(1+\cos x)^{2n-j+1}(1-\cos x)^j\mathrm dx}{\left[\frac{1+a}{1-a}+\cos(x)^2\right]^{n+1}}\tag{2}$$
And from $(1)$, we have that $$N(j,n;a)=\frac1{2(2-2a)^{n+1}}\int_0^\pi\frac{(1+\cos x)^j(1-\cos x)^{2n-j+1}\mathrm dx}{\left[\frac{1+a}{1-a}+\cos(x)^2\right]^{n+1}}\tag{3}$$
So we average $(2)$ and $(3)$ to get
$$\frac1{4(2-2a)^{n+1}}\int_0^\pi\frac{(1+\cos x)^j(1-\cos x)^{2n-j+1}+(1+\cos x)^{2n-j+1}(1-\cos x)^j}{\left[\frac{1+a}{1-a}+\cos(x)^2\right]^{n+1}}\mathrm dx$$
To which we may apply the binomial theorem twice to get 
$$N(j,n;a)=\frac1{4(2-2a)^{n+1}}\sum_{r=0}^{j}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-j+1}R_{r,k}^{j,n}T_{n}^{r,k}(a)$$
Where 
$$R_{r,k}^{j,n}=\left[(-1)^r+(-1)^k\right]{2n-j+1\choose k}{j\choose r}$$
And 
$$T_{n}^{r,k}(a)=\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(x)^{r+k}\mathrm dx}{\left[\frac{1+a}{1-a}+\cos(x)^2\right]^{n+1}}$$
It is probably easier to consider the integral 
$$V_n^{w}(a)=\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(x)^w\mathrm dx}{[a+\cos(x)^2]^{n+1}}\tag{4}$$
So we have that 
$$T_{n}^{r,k}(a)=V_n^{r+k}\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)$$
Other than inventing $V_n^w(a)$, I have been unable to make any progress on the remaining integral. I tried making a tangent-half angle substitution, but that didn't give me any new ideas. I also tried $u=2x$ to get rid of the $\cos(x)^2$ in the denominator of $(4)$, and while it worked, it gave me a nasty $(1+\cos u)^{w/2}$ in the numerator which I could not apply the binomial theorem to unless $w$ was even. In the case of $w=2m$ for $m\in\Bbb N_0$ we would have 
$$V_n^{2m}(a)=2^{n-m+1}\int_0^\pi \frac{(1+\cos u)^m\mathrm du}{(2a+1+\cos u)^{n+1}}$$
Which is, with the binomial theorem,
$$V_n^{2m}(a)=2^{n-m+1}\sum_{i=0}^{m}{m\choose i}\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(u)^i\mathrm du}{(2a+1+\cos u)^{n+1}}$$
$$V_n^{2m}(a)=2^{n-m+1}\sum_{i=0}^{m}{m\choose i}V_n^{i}(2a+1)$$
Although this does not help much either. Could I have some help, preferably with $(4)$? Thanks.

---

**Update**

As we showed, $$V_n^{2m}(a)=2^{n-m+1}\sum_{i=0}^{m}{m\choose i}V_n^{i}(2a+1)$$
This is actually very significant, because I have reason to believe that the definition $$R_{r,k}^{j,n}=\left[(-1)^r+(-1)^k\right]{2n-j+1\choose k}{j\choose r}$$
actually ensures that $r+k$ (that matter) are always going to be even. This is because $$(-1)^r+(-1)^k=\begin{cases}
2 &: r,k\,\text{even}\\
-2 &: r,k\,\text{odd}\\
0 &: \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
And since $\text{even}+\text{even}=\text{even}$ and $\text{odd}+\text{odd}=\text{even}$, we have that 
$$R_{r,k}^{j,n}=0$$
for all odd $r+k$. Hence we have 
$$N(j,n;a)=\frac1{4(2-2a)^{n+1}}\sum_{0\leq r\leq j\\0\leq k\leq 2n-j+1\\ r+k\,\text{even} }C_{r,k}^{j,n}T_{n}^{r,k}(a)$$
With $$C_{r,k}^{j,n}=(-1)^r{2n-j+1\choose k}{j\choose r}$$

> So indeed we need only consider 
>   $$V_n^{2m}(a)=2^{n-m+1}\sum_{i=0}^{m}{m\choose i}V_n^{i}(2a+1)$$
>   Although I am unsure as to how one can find an explicit form of this integral. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As one of the restrictions, did you mean to write $a \geqslant 0$?

Comment: @omegadot I think the integral converges for $a>-1$. I'll edit the post

Comment: This paper mentions the $j=0$ integral and many more and is well worth a read anyway: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ce3b/356b54195cc6c276a94af09484824f973209.pdf

Comment: @Benedict this contains too much advance stuffs bro,a lots of thanks for providing this. I will go through it after i complete the complex analysis and special functions.

Comment: The case for $j>0$ follows from the $N(0,j;a)$ case by taking derivatives with respect to $a$.

Comment: You need $\displaystyle \left\vert{a}\right\vert < 1$ such that $\displaystyle  x^{4} + 2ax^{2} + 1 > 0$.

Comment: @FelixMarin [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/16n8x0dsah) says that I can let $a>-1$ for the integral to converge.

Comment: I want to be sure that the denominator doesn't vanishes out along $\displaystyle\left({0,\infty}\right)$.